# Does background jobs have any event, like OnCreatingJob in aspnetboilerplate startup themplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, quartz

Suppose that we creating SMS job with diffrent type as a input argument:

```
    _backgroundJobManager.Enqueue<SendSMSJob, SendSMSJobArgs>(new SendSMSJobArgs(){type=1});
    _backgroundJobManager.Enqueue<SendSMSJob, SendSMSJobArgs>(new SendSMSJobArgs(){type=2});
```

and want to make a decision to create(or not) background job. does aspnetboilerplate any event mechanism for creating backgroundjobs?

for now one solution is to check SMS type enable state before job creation. 
and another solution is to check sms type enable state inside job.

Comment: first option seems to make more sense to me - but you have the full picture

Comment: First option will be a good fit for on demand job. Second option is good for periodic job (polling of the pending tasks)

Comment: @JohnB suppose that you have hundreds point in your code to send sms, check in every point is not suitable,but with event concept it is more practical

Comment: @Omital - you may want to consider refactoring the code so that the checking logic is reusable  - that way you're not repeating code

Comment: Yup i'm in wrong way. I refactor my code and add SMSManeger and inside it check enable status.